# how to achieve the http://wearehunted.com effect

Tags: ajax, url

I am looking for a way of replicating what the site in the title of this question does. That is, via ajax, changing a part of the page. But, I could not figure out how to change the URL as these things happen.

So, please, help me achieve the effect of url changing on ajax page/change.

Thank you.

(edit ** question rewritten as is appears it was not written well enough, sorry)

Comment: i tried with ie's iframe, but that is a no no it seems as it is not supported by html5. also that doesn't change the url

Comment: **How exactly** it doesn't work? ("no-no" is not very descriptive)

Comment: it works but it is NOT THE SAME EFFECT. the page url remains the same. also it is bad because iframe is deprecated.

Comment: also, i tried ajax, but the page url does not change there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **AJAX** basically updating only parts of a HTML page. Please google for **AJAX tutorials**. Here is a [simple one](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Something like [Jquery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) also do this.

It seems like you want the URL to change. This is the [basic trick](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-history.htm#ajax1.htm) to have history for ajax pages

Comment: thnx. that is good, and i've been able to replicate that, BUT the url of the page does not change.

Comment: @b0x0rz .. If you want the URL to change...please see my edit

Comment: thnx that is exactly it. i will accept when i can (5 minutes). will also rewrite the question as it seems to be not good and ask directly this somehow. thnx